# Firebase analytics - some of my event params is missing in the console log

Tags: firebase, events, console, firebase-analytics

I just added Firebase Analytics to my app and it works just fine.
Im having a problem with the logs of my events on the Firebase console.

I created some custom events.
After they first got in the console i edit the params of every event.
Some of the params added to the event not by me, and every param that was missing i added myself.

I can see the events in the Firebase console, but if i'm getting inside an event some of my params values is missing.

What can i do to make the console adding them too?

adding some pictures:

[image: Firebase analytics console Events]
[image: Custom Event params]
[image: Custom Event params log]